# How to prevent CollabNet SVN from installing duplicate copy of python

Tags: svn

I need a bare-bones version control system with GUI interface. I am developing on windows (single developer, single machine, no remote access required). i read several questions on SO and from what i gathered i could use SVN for version control, and tortoise svn provides the GUI. So i headed off to install svn from [this](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/) link. i installed CollabNet Subversion Edge 1.3.2 (for Windows 32 bit). i already had python installed on my machine, and discovered that collabnet svn installed a duplicate copy of python under c:\csvn.

i have several questions:

1. how to prevent duplicate install of python?
2. am i correct in understanding that i need to install svn from one of the links [here](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html) in addition to tortoise svn?
3. finally is there a better (more light-weight) alternative to what i am doing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you installing only Collabnet SVN ? It should not have any dependency to Python. If it also includes ViewVC, that is what requires python.

Also, I personally use SlikSVN, which I have found to be better.

Edit: I assume you are only looking for a client? If so SlikSVN is good. Also, if that is the case, you should install CollabNet Subversion Command-Line Client from the link that you had given (http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/)

Answer (score 0):

The CollabNet subversion package is useful if you're looking for an "All-In-One" Server setup to server your repositories.  It installs Python due to the way that it handles authentication checks;  I don't know of any way to disable or remediate those checks manually.  If you're just looking for a client package, then you can install many of the client packages that are out there.  TortiseSVN is a standalone subversion package -- meaning that you do not need to install any additional subversion packages when you install the client.

You may want to give WanDisco's [UberSVN](http://www.ubersvn.com) a try -- it was just released on Friday and was easy to setup and use for my small group.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working standalone, then TortoiseSVN provides everything you need.  Just right-click in an empty folder and create a repository, then access it via file:// URL.  For example, C:\Repos becomes file:///repos

Subversion Edge includes Python because it is a providing a full web server UI for Subversion.  The ViewVC repository browser is written in Python and Subversion Edge provides the complete server stack.